# Why would a function resolve properly in the immediate window but not in the visual studio text editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have an interesting situation. I wast trying to figure out how to grab a cookie from an http response and parse it from the header string to something usable. I first tested the solution in the immediate window and it worked, but when I copied it to the text editor the editor is saying that the TryParse function is not found. Why would the immediate window (debugging from the same vs instance) and the text editor disagree on whether a function exists or not?

[image]

After further investigation, I've determined that the reason that the text editor didn't recognize "TryParse" is that my project was using .net 4.6.1 and TryParse isn't available until 4.7.1, but that still doesn't answer why it worked in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the version of .net that the immediate window uses, is not YOUR code, but the latest version of .net framework installed on your machine.

Try running this in the immediate window:

`? Environment.Version`

Mine shows:

```
{3.1.4}
Build: 4
Major: 3
MajorRevision: -1
Minor: 1
MinorRevision: -1
Revision: -1
```